# Google App Engine - updating an entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google App Engine 1.8.3 - Python 2.7 and NDB API as my datastore

Suppose I have a list of group entities displayed on a html table.
And I want to click the name of an individual group to edit the group's information.
What should the key/id of this group be, which one should I use? Please take a look at below

Here's my Model:

```
class Group(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.StringProperty()
```

In my html:

```
......
{% for group in groups %}
    <tr>
       <td>
        <a href="/editGroup?id={{ ????????????? }}" {{ group.name}} </a>
       </td>
       <td>
        {{ group.description}}
       </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
......
```

In the ????? inside the `<a>` tag, what should I put? what should I pass it back to the server? group.key? group.key.id()? or I have to add the Property to Group model as a key property like `groupId = ndb.IntegerProperty()`?

I'm thinking about using the entity's key, but I couldn't find a way to display the key in the html from 'group', like `group.something_to_get_the_key()`.

I was able to get the numeric id using `group.key.id()`, but according to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys
numeric ids might not be unique.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NDB, keys have a `urlsafe()` method which produces a string suitable for use in templates and passing to URLs:

```
{{ group.key.urlsafe }}
```

This is documented on the same page you already link to.

Comment: Note that if it's a jinja2 template it will need to be group.key.urlsafe(), with the brackets.

Comment: Furthermore, it might be worth considering the use of `url_for()` instead of a url path with an id.   You would have an `edit_group(group_id)` function, decorated with a `@route('/editGroup/<string:group_id>')`, and then you would insert in your template `{{ url_for('edit_group', group_id=group.key.id()) }}`.   Which is both more flexible, more elegant and may provide better paths syntax.  This is Flask, but I hear Django has adopted this route scheme lately.